# Collaborative Filtering with SQL

Tags: sql, aggregation, collaborative-filtering

i'm trying to create a recommendation system with sql. Im using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
  UserId INT,
  ProductId INT,
  Rating DECIMAL(3, 1),
  PRIMARY KEY (UserId, ProductId)
);


INSERT INTO TestTable (UserId, ProductId, Rating)
VALUES
  (1, 1001, 4.5),
  (1, 1002, 3.8),
  (1, 1003, 4.2),
  (1, 1004, 3.0),
  (2, 1002, 4.0),
  (2, 1003, 3.5),
  (2, 1005, 4.1),
  (3, 1001, 3.2),
  (3, 1003, 4.5),
  (3, 1004, 4.0),
  (4, 1001, 4.1),
  (4, 1002, 3.9),
  (4, 1004, 3.7),
  (4, 1005, 4.2);
  
  SELECT t2.ProductId
FROM TestTable t1 
INNER JOIN TestTable t2 ON t1.UserId = 1 AND t2.UserId IN (2, 3, 4)
     AND t2.ProductId NOT IN (
         SELECT ProductId
         FROM TestTable
         WHERE UserId = 1
     )
     AND t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
GROUP BY t2.ProductId
HAVING AVG(t2.Rating) >= 3 
     AND COUNT(DISTINCT t2.UserId) >= 3;
```

The code returns zero rows. Maybe anybody here has an idea :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Skip the HAVING clause for a while. Instead put the AVG and COUNT in the SELECT list. Does the new result give you any ideas?

Comment: Writing the pseudocode of what you're attempting to do, and splitting it in specific steps, may help you solve the problem.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do with your code more clearly.   Right off I see that you are linking `t1` (products user 1 has rated) with `t2` (products users 2,3,4 have rated), but then your subquery excludes rows from `t2` where user 1 has rated them.  These are mutually exclusive constraints on your query.  For clarity I would move the conditions out of the join and into a `where` clause, specifically the subquery and `t1.UserId = 1`

Comment: For a recommendation system, I would just query t2 with avg(rating) and count(*), filtering out products that user 1 has rated with your subquery, I don't think you need t1 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the approach I would take:

- gather similar users, according to items they both liked (matching product ids, similar avg rating, at least three products)
- select products of those similar users, whose products are not yet liked by the original user

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t2.UserId
    FROM       TestTable t1 
    INNER JOIN TestTable t2 
            ON t1.UserId = 1 AND t2.UserId IN (2, 3, 4)
           AND t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
    GROUP BY t1.UserId, t2.UserId
    HAVING COUNT(t2.UserId) >= 3
       AND ABS(AVG(t2.Rating - t1.Rating))<1
)
SELECT t1.ProductId
FROM TestTable t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte t2 WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid)
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TestTable t2 WHERE userid = 1 AND t1.ProductID = t2.ProductId)
```

**Output**:

| productid |
| --- |
| 1005 |

Here's a [PostgreSQL demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2T5GP5XkazfqLRTDBDcDrx/1), although this is likely to be working on the most common DBMSs.